# How to extract multiple values from a file in a single pass?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a huge log file (about 6GB) from a simulation. Among the millions of lines in that file, there are two lines that are frequently repeating for a given time:

```
...
Max value of omega = 3.0355
Time = 0.000001
....
Max value of omega = 4.3644
Time = 0.000013
...
Max value of omega = 3.7319
Time = 0.000025
...
...
...
Max value of omega = 7.0695
Time = 1.32125
...
... etc.
```

I would like to extract both "Max value of omega" and "Time" and save them in a single file as columns:

```
#time max_omega
0.000001 3.0355
0.000013 4.3644
0.000025 3.7319
...etc.
```

I proceeded as follows:

```
# The following takes about 15 seconds
grep -F 'Max value of omega' logfile | cut -d "=" -f 2 > max_omega_file.txt
```

, and the same for "Time"

```
# This also takes about 15 seconds
# Very important: match exactly 'Time =' because there other lines that contain the word 'Time'
grep -F 'Time =' logfile | cut -d "=" -f 2 > time.txt
```

Then I need to use the command `paste` to create a two-columns file: Time.txt as the first column and "max_omega_file.txt" as the second column.

As you can see, the time is doubled in the steps above. I wonder if there a single solution to achieve the same results in a single pass so I save some time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^Max/ { s/^.*=\s*//;h; };
        /^Time/{ s/^.*=\s*//;G; s/\n/ /;p; }' infile
```

- match-run syntax `/.../{ ... }`:
  commands within `{...}` will only run on the lines that matched with regex/pattern within `/.../`;
- `s/^.*=\s*//`:
  deletes everything up-to last `=` and whitespaces `\s*` also if there was any.
- `h`:
  copy the result into hold-space
- `G`:
  append the hold-space to pattern-space with embedded newline
- `s/\n/ /`:
  replace that embedded newline with space in the pattern-space
- `p`:
  print pattern-space; you can use `P` command here instead too.

  ```
  0.000001 3.0355
  0.000013 4.3644
  0.000025 3.7319
  1.32125 7.0695
  ```

---

A similar approach proposed by [@stevesliva](/users/93594) that is used `s//<replace>/` which is shorthand to do substitution on the last match:

```
sed -n '/^Max.*=\s*/ { s///;h; };
        /^Time.*=\s*/{ s///;G; s/\n/ /;p; }' infile
```

Comment: the `^Max` regex is not sufficient because there also lines like 'Max iterations' ...etc. The same thing with Time, I want to find literally "Time =" to get the expected line.

Comment: @adhrar_nmatrous you are free to change per your need

Comment: This is the fastest solution so far.

Comment: sed allows use of `//` to repeat last match which might allow some shorthand here. `/^Max.*=\s*/s///h;/^Time.*=\s*/{s///G;s/\n/ /p;}`

Comment: @stevesliva that's a cool feature! I was thinking the same that I wish sed could have this feature but never expect that really have it. amazing, will update my answer with your suggestion. thank you

Answer (score 7):

I can't guarantee it will be faster, but you could do something like this in awk:

```
awk -F' = ' '$1=="Max value of omega" {omega = $2} $1=="Time" {print omega,$2}' file
```

Comment: Hi. For time I need this literally to search for "Time =" (with the = sign) because the word "Time" exist somewhere else. Could you please explain what awk is trying to do?

Comment: @adhrar_nmatrous it splits lines into ` = ` delimited fields then tests the values of the first field. So effectively the second condition matches files that start with exactly `Time = `

Comment: Thank you it works, but it's relatively slow comapred to sed.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "#time", "omega"} /^Max value of omega =/{omega=$NF; next} /^Time =/{print $NF, omega}' file
#time omega
0.000001 3.0355
0.000013 4.3644
0.000025 3.7319
1.32125 7.0695
```

but this will probably be faster:

```
$ grep -E '^(Max value of omega|Time) =' file |
    awk 'BEGIN{print "#time", "omega"} NR%2{omega=$NF; next} {print $NF, omega}'
#time omega
0.000001 3.0355
0.000013 4.3644
0.000025 3.7319
1.32125 7.0695
```

Comment: Certainly, first reducing the data with a grep is the key. Better `grep -A1` for one fixed string from the beginning (to get a few more seconds) and do your formatting based on `NR%3`

Comment: @thanasisp Yeah, I considered that but then I'd have to introduce additional tests to awk to not just do `NR%2` once but to do `NR%3==1` and then `NR%3==2` or introduce a variable to hold the `NR%3` result first... it just seemed like any potential speed up from the grep would be lost by the additional awk comparisons and it just wasn't worth bothering with.

Comment: It won't be lost, some lines of some MB will match from the total of 6GB. And yes the `NR%3==1` or `2` hardcoded seems good. If 3 of 6 GB are matching, I wouldn't be sad, and think of one or two tests, awk is for formatting here, assuming real file inputs.

Comment: All I'm saying is that while the grep should (but may not be, idk) faster the awk will be slower, and overall I doubt if there'll be much difference in execution speed between the 2 approaches. I could be wrong of course but I don't care enough to test it.

Comment: Overall, the second command (awk here) will spend a lot of its lifetime idle, waiting for the next line (for real cases, assuming 0-10% of the file lines matching).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```bsh
paste \
  <(<file awk -F= '$1 ~ /omega/ {print $2}') \
  <(<file awk -F= '$1 ~ /Time/ {print $2}')
```

I think even

```
<file grep -o '[[:digit:].]*' | paste - -
```

Or

```
<file cut -d= -f2 | paste - -
```

Would do

Answer (score 0):

[`grep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) may search for multiple patterns in one go

> -e PATTERNS, --regexp=PATTERNS
> Use PATTERNS as the patterns.  **If this option is used multiple
> times** or is combined with the -f (--file) option, **search for
> all patterns given**.  This option can be used to protect a
> pattern beginning with “-”.

So

```
grep -F -e 'Max value of omega = ' -e 'Time = ' logfile
```

will reduce the size of the search space. Then you can post process with one of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative perhaps simpler sed solution would be

```
sed -nr 'N;s/^Max value of omega = ([0-9.]+)\nTime = ([0-9.]+)$/\1 \2/p;D;' logfile
```

where 'N' adds a second line to pattern space, the 's/pattern/string/p' block seeks the two line pattern and prints out the two capture groups (\1 \2) separated by space, and finally D discards the first line from pattern space.

One advantage of this approach that I've used in past when seeking multi-line patterns is you can print out the capture groups in an arbitrary order, not necessarily the order they appear in the file.
So that in your example if you wanted "Time" in the first column you can simply do this

```
sed -nr 'N;s/^Max value of omega = ([0-9.]+)\nTime = ([0-9.]+)$/\2 \1/p;D;' logfile
```

Note it now says "\2 \1" rather than "\1 \2".